# Admin CMD check disk when I restart

Tags: cmd

I'm running

```
  chkdsk /f /r
```

to schedule a check disk when I restart the PC.

Is there a way to automatically shutdown the  PC after the  check disk has completed??

Answer (score 0):

You can try via Startup; Press Windows + R and type **shell:startup** and click on ok. This is will open the startup folder, create a notepad and type `shutdown -s -t 300` this will give 300s or 5mins before shutdown happens. Save the file as **shutdown.bat** save as type: **All files**. Copy that file to the start up folder and schedule the `chkdsk` when the system boot it will trigger the shutdown. To abort the timer just press Windows + R and type `shutdown -a` This will abort the process. Go to the startup folder and delete the file.